# typedef array of constant length

Tags: c++, c, typedef

What does this do and how?

```
typedef int map_t [1<<MAX];
```

What does that line do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `MAX` is a constant known at compile-time, then this code:

```
typedef int map_t [1<<MAX];
map_t x;
```

is the same as this code:

```
int x[1 << MAX];
```

Comment: ... which is not a bitmask but an array of `pow(2, MAX)` integers.

Comment: @Dimme `<<` is the "left shift" operator. It shifts all the bits in the first operand to left a number of bits equal to the second operand. `a << b` is roughly equivalent to `a * pow(2, b)`.

Comment: Why isn't the syntax like this: `typedef int[1<<MAX] map_t;` ?

Comment: @user: In general, the syntax for a typedef is exactly like a standard variable definition, but with the variable name substituted for the typedef name.  So `int x[BLAH]` becomes `typedef int map_t[BLAH]`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth But what you say works if syntax was `typedef int[1<<MAX] map_t;` (substitute typedef with map_t)

Comment: @user: No it isn't!  I just literally swapped `x` for `map_t`.

Comment: I mean what you say works for this syntax too: `typedef int[8] map_t;`

Comment: @user: `int[8] x` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume MAX is defined as 8:

```
typedef int map_t[1<<MAX];
```

is same as

```
typedef int map_t[256];
```

because `1 << 8` = 256. It means shift bits in the number 1 8 times to the left like so:

1 is 0000 0001 in binary

after 1 shift:

0000 0010, which is 2 in decimal

after 8 shifts:

1 0000 0000, which is 256 in decimal

So there is no bitmasking here, it's just easy way to say

```
typedef int map_t[pow(2,MAX)];
```

I haven't done C much but the above should compile, right?

Edit: The above doesn't compile but if we were to dynamically allocate it should work.

Comment: Using the function `pow` in an array index might not compile, depending on a number of things.  But a good explanation.

Comment: no it does not compile because the array bound must be integer constant. (the return type of pow() is double too, but the more important thing is that it is not constant: `typedef int map_t [(int)pow(2,MAX)]` will not work too)

Comment: Hmm... so would this work? `double tmp = pow(2, MAX); typedef int map_t[(int)tmp];` Sorry I don't really know much C at all :P But the principles at hand are the same in many languages

Comment: @Esailija: No. It doesn't work because that value is integer but not constant and it's value will be calculated after compiling the code.(when it runs)

Comment: @user913461, yes I tried various things with pow and can't get it to compile so it cannot be compared to pow(2,MAX) unless you allocate dynamically which is not the case here.